# Matrix of Radio button in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch-2

Can anybody help me making a matrix of radiobutton in sencha touch .and the structure of the matrix will be defined in  JSON File.
Here is the image of what i want to achieve

Comment: I don't see an image :)

Comment: yeah because i cant upload image untill i have more reputation but its  you can find the image in this link .http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?151477-How-to-create-a-matrix-style-table

Answer (score 0):

You might find the dataview component useful in creating what you want. Here is [demo](http://www.senchafiddle.com/#HWu1K) with a fairly complex layout drawn.

Comment: i gave you the link above of the image.your ans not fullfilling my requirements .neverthless  Thanks                                             here is the link again http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?151477-How-to-create-a-matrix-style-table